# Implementing has-list in scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme, computer-science

how can you implement a Scheme function has-list recursively, which tests whether a list contains other list as an element. For example (has-list '(1 2 3)) should return false, and (has-list '(1 2 (3 4) 5)) should return true.

Comment: Spizzy - we aren't just an answer service, we like to see people try things first.

Answer (score 1):

If your implementation has something like `ormap`, then:

```
(define (has-list? l) (ormap list? l))
```

Using `or` as in Dan D.'s answer will not work.

Comment: `ormap` is not available before r6rs.

Comment: (1) I started it with an "if"; (2) R6RS *is* Scheme; (3) even in pre-R6RS schemes such a function is very common -- for example, SRFI-1's [`any`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#any).

Answer (score 1):

A list has a list as an element iff it is not the empty list and either its first element is a list or the rest of the list has a list as an element.  The translation to Scheme code is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it recursively and without using map:

```
 (define (has-list? lst)
    (cond
      ((null? lst) #f)
      ((list? (car lst)) #t)
      (else (has-list? (cdr lst)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (has-list? X) (apply or (map list? X)))
```

Comment: this doesn't work if `or` is a macro (as it is in racket (plt-scheme))