# How do you find list of a list inside the Scheme list?

Tags: list, scheme, computer-science

I am working on an assignment and I need to find a list inside of a list.  For example, if we have

```
(has-list? '(1 2 (3 4) 5))
```

than it will return true because `(3 4)` is a list inside of a bigger list.

Comment: What have you tried?  Why do you think it didn't work?  We can help you with specific points, but we're not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing has-list in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135989/implementing-has-list-in-scheme)

Comment: This exact question was already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135989/implementing-has-list-in-scheme/5136459

Answer (score 2):

The function `(list? l)` will return `#t` if `l` is a list, and `#f` if it's not

```
(define (has-list l)
  (if (null? l)
      _____
      (or (________) (_________))))
```

fill in the blanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the Scheme implementation in hand provides a library function like `any` which expects a predicate and a list as arguments to test any existence of an element in the list satisfying the predicate, you can simply write `(any list? '(1 2 (3 4) 5))`, otherwise, do fill the blanks prelic left for you.